# Reduce the number of AsyncTask in Room DataBase Repository

Tags: java, android, android-room, android-database

I am trying to simplify the number of lines for my codes in the repository.
Currently there is a lot of repetition in my codes.

Many of the solutions online only involves inserting once into the table.
I need to do insert() on many tables. I want to reduce the repetition for writing the same inner AsyncTask for inserting different data into different table

This is the codes for the repository class

```
public class CharacterRepository {
    private UserDao rUserDao;
    private  CharacterDao rCharacterDao;
    private EquipementDao rEquipementDao;

    private LiveData<List<UserDao>> rUserLD;
    private LiveData<List<CharacterDao>> rCharacterLD;
    private LiveData<List<EquipmentDao>> rEquipmentLD;

    // Constructor that handles the database and initialise the member variables
    CharacterRepository(Application application){
        MyDatabase db = MyDatabase.getDatabase(application);
        rUserDao = db.userDao();
        rCharacterDao = db.characterDao();
        rEquipementDao = db.EquipmentDao();

        rUserLD = rUserDao.getAllUser();
        rCharacterLD = rCharacterDao.getAllChar();
        rEquipmentLD = rEquipementDao.getAllEquip();
    }

    // Wrapper method that returns cached entities as LiveData
    public LiveData<List<UserEntity>> getAllUser(){return rUserLD;}
    public LiveData<List<CharEntity>> getAllChar(){return rCharacterLD;}
    public LiveData<List<EquipEntity>> getAllEquip(){return rEquipmentLD;}

    /*---------------------the start of the problem-------------------*/
    //Wrapper method: calling insert on non-UI Thread
    public void insert(UserEntity userEntity){new insertUserAsyncTask(rUserDao).execute(userEntity);}
    public void insert(CharacterEntity characterEntity){new insertCharacterAsyncTask(rCharacterDao).execute(characterEntity);}
    public void insert(EquipmentEntity equipmentEntity){new insertEquipAsyncTask(rCharacterDao).execute(equipmentEntity);}


    /*-------------------THIS IS THE PART WHERE I WANT TO REDUCE THE CODE REDUNDANCY THE CODES ARE DOING THE SAME THING-------------------*/
    private static class insertUserAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<UserEntity, Void, Void> {
        private UserDao mAsyncTaskDao;

        insertUserAsyncTask(UserDao dao) {mAsyncTaskDao = dao;}

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(UserEntity... userEntities) {
            mAsyncTaskDao.save(params[0]);
            return null;
        }
    }
    private static class insertCharacterAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<CharacterEntity, Void, Void> {
        private CharacterDao mAsyncTaskDao;
        insertCharacterAsyncTask(CharacterDao dao) {mAsyncTaskDao = dao; }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(CharacterEntity... characterEntities) {
            mAsyncTaskDao.save(params[0]);
            return null;
        }
    }
    private static class insertEquipAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<, Void, Void> {
        private EquipmentDao mAsyncTaskDao;
        insertEquipAsyncTask(EquipmentDao dao) {mAsyncTaskDao = dao;}

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(EquipmentEntity... equipmentEntities) {
            mAsyncTaskDao.save(params[0]);
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

I still have other insert methods and I need to call delete and update as well. I do not want the codes to so repetitive

Comment: Just use what Room already offers: Single<YourEntity> or Completable  responses, and forget about AsyncTasks.

Comment: Hmm, use Threadpoolexecutor pattern way, it's thread reuseable and neat

Comment: @notTdar, I do not have a onCreate method to initialise my ThreadPoolExecutor

Comment: @ror can you provide more details as to the feature on what room offers? I still have many methods which I need to implement for my database

Comment: @Peter, pasted some links, the threadpoolclass, how to implement and how to request/insert, all will be doing in background thread and thread reuse will happen, do read about java executor, threadpoolexecutor to grasp the concept in later.These are great in db scenario cases.

Comment: @Peter, also learn mvp

Comment: @Zoe oh thanks, never knew android studio tag is only for the IDE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so, @notTdar came up with this solution

Have a class call ThreadPoolExecutor.

Call this class to execute all the DAO from the Android Room Database

- Call `cleanResource();` in `onDestroy`
- Call `shut();` in `onPause`

ThreadPoolExecutorHelper.java

```
public class ThreadPoolExecutorHelper {
        private static final String TAG = ThreadPoolExecutorHelper.class.getSimpleName() + " : ";
        private static final boolean LOG_DEBUG = false;

        private static volatile ThreadPoolExecutorHelper INSTANCE;
        private ThreadPoolExecutor mThreadPoolExecutor;
        private BlockingQueue<Runnable> mBlockingQueue;
        private static final int TASK_QUEUE_SIZE = 12;

        //core size, keeps thread : along with running + idle
        private static final int CORE_POOL_SIZE = 5;

        // pool size
        private static final int MAX_POOL_SIZE = 5;

        // core pool size exceeds, idle thread will wait for this time before termination.
        private static final long KEEP_ALIVE_TIME = 20L;

        public static ThreadPoolExecutorHelper getInstance() {
            if (LOG_DEBUG) Log.e(TAG, "getInstance: ");
            if (INSTANCE == null) {
                synchronized (ThreadPoolExecutorHelper.class) {
                    if (INSTANCE == null) {
                        INSTANCE = new ThreadPoolExecutorHelper();
                    }
                }
            }
            return INSTANCE;
        }

        private ThreadPoolExecutorHelper() {
            if (LOG_DEBUG) Log.d(TAG, "ctor: ");
            initBlockingQueue();
            initThreadPoolExecutor();
        }

        // submit Runnables
        public void submitRunnable(Runnable task) {
            if (LOG_DEBUG) Log.d(TAG, "submitRunnable: " + task.getClass().getSimpleName());

            //in case, init again, if null.
            initBlockingQueue();
            initThreadPoolExecutor();
            mThreadPoolExecutor.execute(task);
        }

        // shut the threadpool
        public synchronized void shut() {
            if (LOG_DEBUG) Log.d(TAG, "shut: ");
            if (mThreadPoolExecutor != null) {
                mThreadPoolExecutor.shutdown();
                try {
                    mThreadPoolExecutor.awaitTermination(6000L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    if (LOG_DEBUG) Log.w(TAG, "shut: InterruptedException");
                    mThreadPoolExecutor.shutdownNow();
                }
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "shut: mThreadPoolExecutor instance NULL");
            }
        }

        //clean up
        public void cleanResources() {
            if (LOG_DEBUG) Log.e(TAG, "cleanResources: ");
            if (INSTANCE != null) {
                if (mThreadPoolExecutor != null) {
                    mThreadPoolExecutor = null;
                }
                if (mBlockingQueue != null) {
                    mBlockingQueue = null;
                }
                nullifyHelper();
            }
        }

        private static void nullifyHelper() {
            if (INSTANCE != null) {
                INSTANCE = null;
            }
        }

        private void initBlockingQueue() {
            if (mBlockingQueue == null) {
                mBlockingQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>(TASK_QUEUE_SIZE);
            }
        }

        private void initThreadPoolExecutor() {
            if (mThreadPoolExecutor == null) {
                mThreadPoolExecutor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(CORE_POOL_SIZE, MAX_POOL_SIZE,
                        KEEP_ALIVE_TIME, TimeUnit.SECONDS, mBlockingQueue);
            }
        }
    }
```

Add this codes in `onCreate` (activity) or `onViewCreated`(Fragment)
This will initialise the `ThreadPoolExecutorHelper` by calling `getInstance()`

```
private void initExecutorHelper() {
    if (LOG_DEBUG) Log.d(TAG, "initExecutorHelper: ");
    if (mExecutorHelper == null) {
        mExecutorHelper = ThreadPoolExecutorHelper.getInstance();
    }
}
```

This is the `insert();` method to start a Thread
You can change this to do insert, query, delete task from the DAO in Room Database

```
public void insert() {
        if (LOG_DEBUG) Log.d(TAG, "requestQREntityList: whatKind= " + whatKind);
        mExecutorHelper.submitRunnable(() -> {
        if (!Thread.interrupted()) {
        //request a list or inset something, write your logic.

        } else {
        if (LOG_DEBUG) Log.e(TAG, "run: Thread is interrupted");
        }
        });
        }
```